# Change VLC interface style in terminal

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, zsh, themes

I searched through the [`vlc`](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) docs (`vlc -H --advanced --help-verbose`) but couldn't find a way to do this. Is it not possible to change the interface style to dark in terminal?

[image]

Bonus question: How about disabling automatic icon changes?

[image]

Comment: I think you can simply change the config file with some command line tools (like _sed_). It seems you are using MacOS, so according to the [VLC Wikipage](https://wiki.videolan.org/Preferences/) the config file is `~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/vlcrc`. My Linux version of _vlc_ does not have the setting you are interested in, so you need to investigate the setting yourself. Just open the config file with an editor, but make sure that _vlc_ isn't running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice in @mpy's comment, this gets the job done:

```sh
# Ensure the settings file exists (not created on install but on launch)
# by calling vlc with an invalid value for the interface option.
# Does nothing except create and populate the file
# ~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/vlcrc
vlc -I none

# Enable dark mode.
sed -i '' -E 's/#?macosx-interfacestyle=0/macosx-interfacestyle=1/' ~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/vlcrc
# Disable icon changes (e.g. Christmas icon)
sed -i '' -E 's/#?macosx-icon-change=1/macosx-icon-change=0/' ~/Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/vlcrc
```